# Variable and slow internet speed on my Mac compared to other devices connected on the same network

Tags: macos, imac, internet, internet-sharing

Background:
I have a 40 Mbps Ethernet connection hooked directly to my iMac running on Mojave.

I use the Mac as a router to share the internet connection from Ethernet to other devices using WiFi.

Problem:
WiFi-connected devices are easily hitting 15-20 Mbps download speeds, but the Mac, being directly connected to Ethernet, only reaches download speeds up to 4 Mbps!

I don't know what's the reason behind this.

Comment: There's a python based speedtest `brew install speedtest-cli` you might want to try if you aren't measuring the speeds from the router. I'm able to see full bandwidth on ubiquiti / speed test and all Macs in the last 10 years should be able to get 40Mbit over ethernet if there's not a problem with the OS or software. How are you measuring the bandwidth? (and does it show buffer bloat or can you control for other devices hogging the bandwidth)

Comment: See on speed test results it's showing 40 now it's not a 1:1 connection so after dividing I am supposed to get around 15 down; which is true, but, the issue is with the mac for example if I download a 1GB file on my mac, the internet speed remains within 4 Mbps max whereas the same file downloads on my phone at a speed of 10-15 Mbps

Comment: @Sayan - can you describe how the iMac is being used as a router for all the other devices a bit more? The networking setup is confusing in your description.

Comment: @slm My Mac directly connects to the internetet via the Ethernet port, now I use the internet sharing menu under system preferences to broadcast the Mac's internet over WI-FI to other devices

Comment: Does the problem disappear when you turn off the WiFi routing?

Comment: @IconDaemon On/Off same issue